# Is this sentence compound?

Tags: sentence-structure

1. Jack and Jill went up the hill.

or

2. Shakespeare is a poet and dramatist.

In the above two sentences what confused me is the subject phrase or the complement phrase. If Jack and Jill is the subject phrase thereby making the first one a simple sentence, relying upon the same principle, "poet and dramatist" is a noun phrase working as a complement and should render the second sentence a simple sentence as well. But everywhere it is a compound sentence. Why?

It may appear to be an elementary question; but sometimes its apparent innocence becomes mind boggling.

Comment: They are both 'simple' sentences.

Comment: "But every where it is a compound sentence" — who says they're compound sentences & what's their rationale? Compound variants would be something like "Jack went up the hill, and Jill came also". "Shakespeare was not just a poet but he was also a dramatist" — where you have what could be two standalone phrases linked by a conjunction.

Comment: So a clause(s) with finite verb(s) or atleast one elliptical sentence(s) joined by coordinator to the principal clause is necessary for a sentence to be compound.Thank you BillJ and anotherdave.

Comment: @BaridBaranAcharya Ellipsis has nothing to do with it. A compound sentence is defined as one that has two or more independent clauses linked by coordination: "[I like beer] and [Ed likes wine]"; "[I like this hat] but [I don't like this coat]".

Comment: Ok,thank you once again !